# Flutter keyboard makes textField hidden

Tags: flutter

I have a problem, when the textfield is tapped, the flutter keyboard opens up and it cover almost the whole the screen, including the TextField.

I've tried all the solutions I've seen online:

- Wrapping the widget in a SingleScrollView
- constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
- Set Scaffold to not resizeonBottom

Still, the keyboard is hiding the textField.

This is what I did:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          [....................]
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: TheBaseColors.lightRed,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'FoundersGrotesqueXCond',
                ),
                onTap: () {},
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'OCCUPATION',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: TheBaseColors.lightRed),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: TheBaseColors.lightRed),
                  ),
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: TheBaseColors.lightRed),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your single child in an scaffold and set the property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to true. So when you tap something in this page, the keyboard will push your page up to not cover your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
child: ....
)
```

---

```
Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _msgController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          // width: 0.0 produces a thin "hairline" border
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60.0)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          //borderSide: const BorderSide(),
                        ),
                        hintStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                        hintText: 'write here...'),
                  ),
                ),
)
```

Add this

Answer (score 0):

I personally experienced the scroll problem mentioned above with the Flutter versions 3.10 and later. Therefore, based on my own experience, I recommend using version 3.7.12 to avoid encountering this issue.